# Edição básica de imagens utilizando OpenCV

Tags: c++, edição-de-imagens, opencv

Olá, estou aprendendo a utilizar os recursos que o OpenCV oferece para processamento de imagens e surgiu a seguinte dúvida:

**Como eu faço para editar somente uma área pré-determinada de uma imagem?**

Para facilitar o entendimento da minha dúvida, vou utilizar a função `cv::cvtColor()` e alterar uma imagem de colorida (RGB) para escala de cinza (Gray Scale), porém gostaria que a solução proposta funcione com qualquer outra função. O que já consegui fazer:

**Carregar e Exibir uma imagem do disco:**

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/home/anderson/Pictures/Outras/house.jpeg");
if (img.empty()) {
    std::cout << "Falha ao carregar o arquivo do disco!" << std::endl;
}

cv::namedWindow("RGB");
cv::imshow("RGB", img);
```

[image: Resultado]

**Selecionar uma área e transformar em escala de cinza:**

```
cv::Mat imgMod(img, cv::Rect(100,100,150,150));
cv::Mat imgModOut;
cv::cvtColor(imgMod, imgModOut, CV_BGR2GRAY);

cv::namedWindow("Gray");
cv::imshow("Gray", imgModOut);
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Até ai tudo certo, porém **como eu faço para combinar o recorte cinza com a imagem original e criar uma nova imagem parcialmente cinza (área recortada)?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O que você está procurando pode ser alcançado através da definição de uma **ROI** (*Region of Interest* - Região de Interesse) na imagem original.

**Uma ROI especifica uma área de interesse dentro de uma imagem** e possibilita extrair esta subregião para um novo `cv::Mat`, ou inserir uma outra imagem dentro desta. São exatamente estes procedimentos que o código a seguir demonstra para realizar o efeito que você busca:

```
// Carregar a imagem de teste a partir do disco.
cv::Mat input = cv::imread("house.png");
if (input.empty())
{
    std::cout << "!!! imread(): arquivo não encontrado" << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

// Especificar a localização da ROI, assumindo que: 
// x,y = (190,230)   
// largura, altura = (260, 60)
cv::Rect roi = cv::Rect(190, 230, 260, 60);

// Criar uma nova imagem a partir da ROI setada na imagem original:
cv::Mat sub_img = input(roi);
//cv::imwrite("house_roi.png", sub_img);
```

Neste momento, **sub_img** armazena:

[image]

```
// Converter a subárea para tons de cinza.
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(sub_img, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
//cv::imwrite("house_gray.png", gray);
```

**gray** armazena:

[image]

É importante ressaltar que essa conversão de imagem colorida para tons de cinza cria uma nova imagem com apenas 1 canal de cor. Portanto, é essencial criarmos um novo `cv::Mat` com 3 canais de cores antes de copiarmos a subimagem para dentro da imagem original (que possui 3 canais); caso contrário, o OpenCV vai reclamar que os números de canais das imagens são diferentes.

```
// Converter subárea de 1 canal de cor para 3 canais. Esta operação não afeta os pixels da imagem.
cv::Mat tmp;
cv::cvtColor(gray, tmp, CV_GRAY2BGR);
//cv::imwrite("house_tmp.png", tmp);

// Copiar a subimagem para dentro da imagem original, na localização especificada pela ROI.
tmp.copyTo(input(roi));
//cv::imwrite("house_result.png", input);
```

Quando `copyTo()` é executado, os pixels de `tmp` são inseridos na imagem original, obedecendo a subárea especificada por `roi`.

No final deste processo, `input` armazena:

[image]

Comment: *Como transformar seu amigo em um índio, usando OpenCV.*

Comment: A imagem original utilizada na demonstração pode ser [encontrada aqui](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mhzKm.png).

Comment: É bom deixar claro que não é Lúpus.

Comment: @karlphillip Obrigado pela excelente resposta, funcionou perfeitamente!